# Group Pages based on Parent in Admin Area

Tags: pages, admin, wp-admin

EDIT: I've managed to solve this with the help of Reddit. For those interested I used [Admin Column View](http://wordpress.org/plugins/admin-column-view/)

---

My website has about 50 pages separated under 5 parent pages. In the backend it is a mess of pages, and when I give this website to the client they're going to have no idea what to do with it.

The pages span across 3 pages of next buttons, can I group these pages by their parent page so that they're hidden until the parent page is clicked on? Preferably a plugin or something similarly simple to use.

Just so there are 5 pages rather than 50 to scroll through.

The way it is displayed now:

```
Parent
- Child
- Child 2
- Child 3
```

Is really un-client friendly.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why is that un-client friendly? Plugin recommendations are generally off topic here.

Comment: Assume that the clients I'm dealing with barely know how to save a Word Doc in the right place.